# How to compare value in array with value in multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

It's my problem.

```
 $arr_1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
 $arr_2 = [
    [
      "word" => "g"
    ],
    [
      "word" => "a"
    ]
 ]
```

So i want check

if `$arr_2[n]["word"]` value same `$arr_1`, then return `true`

Thanks you for help !!

Comment: Use `array_diff();` to compare `$result = array_diff($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should basically be the contents of your function

```
foreach($arr_2 as $words){
    if(in_array($words['word'], $arr_1)
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank youuuu !! It's simple, the first time i tried

`array_search($words, array_column($arr_2, "word"))` in for loop,


But your solution is very nice, thanks you again !!